# How to allow flash player to have controll over mic & cam

Tags: 14.04, flash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm a big Karaoke fan and like to sing karaoke but the site I use for my karaoke uses flash player and ask me to let flash have control over my mic and cam and when I tried to click on ok it won't let me me. The site is [singsnap.com](http://singsnap.com). If you go to that site and try to record a song it will pop up and you will see what I'm trying to say. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long known bug unfortunately.
See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+bug/865672

On some sites, like youtube you can work around this by making the flash window fullscreen and then using the dialog (for some reason this works). But unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option like that on your karaoke website.

Answer (score 1):

I have found after installing google chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I was able to check allow on flash player to have control over my mic and cam.But it will not let you on fire fox.